MySQL ordering for main and sub elements in a single query
My MySQL table looks like this:



_id
_masterid




17
null


18
17


19
17


20
null


21
null


22
20


23
17


24
20


25
20



Is it possible to order it with a single query so we get this results as output?



_id
_masterid




17
null


18
17


19
17


23
17


20
null


22
20


24
20


25
20


21
null



_ids without _masterid are main comments, and _ids with _masterids are replies. So ideally I'd like to order comment and its replies bunched up together, before proceeding to the next comment.
Thanks!

why "17:null" is at the first place, "20:null" is in the middle of ordered result and "21:nul" at the end?

@Alex because 22,24 and 25 have 20 as their _masterid. Then the next _id without _masterid is 21.

even if that is your fantasy and you think there is a logic behind (but that is not logic) it does not explain why "21:null" shouldn't go right after "20:null"? But you should rethink of what you are trying to achieve

Allow me to rephrase it: _id=20 is a main comment. _ids 22, 24 and 25 are replies to that main comment, hence linked via _masterid = 20; I'm trying to get the order of main comment followed by its replies, then the next main comment and so on.

Yes, it is possible:
select
    *
from
    `my_table`
order by
    coalesce(`_masterid`, `_id`),
    `_masterid` is not null

The coalesce(_masterid, _id) part returns either _masterid if it's not NULL, or _id otherwise. Then you put the parent thread first by placing _masterid being NULL before the non-NULL ones.

Thanks! That did it. May I also enquire if there is a known performance hit on bigger tables for using Coalesce? In the meantime I've worked out that if _masterid (where it is null) is set to that row's _id, I can order the table by _masterid ASC, _id ASC and get the same results. I wonder which one would be faster on a big table.

I would recommend to fill parent (_masterid) with self value.
So whenever you initiate the comment or whatever topic like: (17, null), (20, null) you do  (17, 17), (20, 20).
This approach will allow you to do simple order with regular indexes in use:
SELECT _id, _masterid
FROM my_table
ORDER by _masterid, _id

The approach of Robo Robok is good. But it will have small performance issue because it uses the function result for ordering which is slower than regular indexes.

Thanks Alex! I've just responded to Robo Robok with this very same solution (got hit by a big brain moment and worked it out while waiting for answers), wondering which one's faster. I think you've answered that question of mine too.
